# Generically obtaining a struct's own type at its top level

Tags: c++, types

Is there a way to generically get the type of a `struct`, at the top-level in the declaration of said `struct`, *without* referring to the actual name of the `struct` itself?

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct example {
    using attempt1 = example; // <- obvious, but not what I want
    using attempt2 = decltype(*this); // <- error
    using attempt3 = std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type; // <- error
};
```

Or:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct { // anonymous
    //using attempt1 = ...;
    using attempt2 = decltype(*this);
    using attempt3 = std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type;
} x;
```

Those programs of course fail to compile ("invalid use of 'this' at top level") in C++17 and C++2a mode on GCC 9.x and 10.x, but I'd like to do something like `attempt2` or `attempt3` where I can get the `struct`'s type without referring to its name ("`example`" in the first case).

Is this possible?

I took a look through [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) but nothing popped out at me, and I couldn't think of where else to look.

Comment: Closest thing I could find was this, see if it somehow helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26274842/791430

or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232825/791430

Google this with the word `class` rather than `struct` for better results

Comment: maybe this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649278/how-can-i-get-the-class-name-from-a-c-object

Comment: Can you do a `template <class T> class SelfTypeHolder { using SelfType = T; }; ` and use it like `class SomeClass: public SelfTypeHolder<SomeClass>{}; `, like the curiously recurring template?

Comment: Unfortunately it appears the available solutions only work when used in non-static functions of the struct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Well, if I understand you correctly, the thing about that is `SelfTypeHolder<SomeClass>` still refers to `SomeClass` by its actual name, so for example, I'm not sure (maybe there's a way but I don't know it) how to use that in e.g. an anonymous `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Friend injection to the rescue!

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAGYAHKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiACsnUgAdUBUJ1Wj1DE3MrAKC1OntHFyN3Tx9FZUxVEIYCZmICMONTSzSVWNps3IJ45zcPb18FHLyCiOLGyurE5PqASkVUA2JkDgByWmYjTAU/ZmGAajwjP1ZxAAYAQXEAdlkNuf258cnp2cw19YO57d2Ly4OCTCXhB6uzHQIATz8tCcw5gBVxGZsOc7gdGsQDKo5jlgFcdnMDEFRDCvn8gQARAFA6TwjE486gsEwx7LZgvIE6BwEOa2IEgvbEiFQmnMdCsAD6sKJYOuPOJ%2ByoxDwNjmaFojUwAA8/MQ5swDER5eyOVQDLRkBA2ZzuW86cCegTGbytvizDd%2BZcHk9yei3tTaaRUd8jn9AcDLeCCJDodqOQB3YUPYie/Z840CuZCkXaMV0SUyuUKpV%2BtUarUq3U6fXYHrw6TETAEQa0GHMYCU90gnbbM2yU2hvFGzYRy4AN1QeHQys5ac1ecxcyw7Aezcb1rJFPt9Fp9MbzN9KsLbI8jfDt0jiORcM%2B31eWN3P0mQ4yrEPGd76s1fqzOb5pp6PRAIEPzYFtbfBw/Gw/5sJP8kMwsCoBw/gAaScAB5AB1BgOQYbBbAAMQ5f4AE0AAVsCuLwdH5cQvFkQijGYD53A5dUkUwdACPxLwsQ7Ls5iUVgqC5NEOQQZRvmIDl0GMIwPggAdcPwhECLw1sDggRj0CfEBFmWZ8/UDQhVzeDkOVsABJJxsE0p1GnQZ9CyMVA20wDlkDbQs2IISksGQM80QgAAqAgEDwBRDQ9D0awbc0cMkjc8SC/DCII6QSLIyzKKUGj6No5icjUZB5UVVBmOUOyOK41geOEsKI2uIqQsuQti2IUtn0U1hlKXTAVxDDStN0/SOTnfy61Ky5vxbTZAOA0C5gQ5DUMw7DHOc74IBYnLvk47iPGE%2BTXx/ACzAcJyDCwV4qUCb1GqMOcNq2wxdspQ8HBoE7%2BoXGl%2BvXS4IJguDRpQ9CsP/EL2lSuZZKjVBUGEsSbgFIznzQRU9spZ1MC7CB3vGrCegAOldQrKVhsARgk2gcc/MMGx/AKLQ2B0SIcEGSbBg51mfGhgZ83EAHoWbmDDhXoBQrgANlWThNn5uYIBI0R2G7cR%2BaF1Y0cJYn1hGPo6pGLwRlIUwRlWdXUBAEY8JkORmIGIZ0UAzh1YIPXtcfUgAGtvC8VGAE5OF5wDVjMXnee4Z3JE4LwhD17h1c17XSF1kZ1YUEBVlIK2taV0g4FgGBEBQVAljwdgyAoCA0CznOUGEUROE4VY45As8PBjiBXGt9XXAcXIPj1i3SALyZ6Eg2hWFbxPSCwMXgHYBvB7wQtMgsmOB%2BlDJFVGcPqWUMfWDwVxiBbvQsDby3hSMXe%2BhoegmDYDgeH4QQS7EOQ5CEdeY8gPpUD8MoZ4AWiMzEJENmRJFWOY79oJsFYIA6C0pvTMEAd8dAIhUrvw8MQEgCho7pEyBoCANgWimF8DYTotRPC%2BGiMEOg2DBDELKPgpIdQGhoLKBUZo%2BhCiCBYhkehTQqigS6DQxQHCyENA4VQ7onA%2BgKBNsMLgys9Zqw1mPSOUoLC83fj7MU185hl1RqsTRItcCEBIFcc2To9CFw8AYswIi5gG1kDIS2DdbZcSapQKRIwQ6kAPl4OOYcdZ62jrHeOdjk5pwgEgAYBA/CKnIJQAufhs48OonowhpBj6MBYKPcupBAzMD8IfIOqtQ5yL1lIcxcx/SEAQHMBRSiVFOREHCDRWjw4Jxtn0BxWBPDCXtt4OOKtXHuM8QUqOig/FNKVn0B23BuCaIsGYLYvNna8zMGYDxWwLCBxVmYfJA9I62MTrbFWkhNnh22f43ZfQLLECCBobgQA)</kbd>

```
namespace impl
{
    namespace
    {
        template <typename T>
        struct tag { using type = T; };

        template <int L>
        struct adl_tag
        {
            friend constexpr auto adl_func(adl_tag<L>);
        };

        template <int L, typename T>
        struct adl_writer
        {
            friend constexpr auto adl_func(adl_tag<L>) {return tag<T>{};}
        };

        void adl_func() = delete;

        template <int L>
        struct adl_reader
        {
            using type = typename decltype(adl_func(adl_tag<L>{}))::type;
        };
    }
};

#define KNOWS_SELF_TYPE \
    [[maybe_unused]] void self_type_helper_dummy() \
    { \
        (void)::impl::adl_writer<__LINE__, std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*this)>>{}; \
    } \
    [[maybe_unused]] static auto self_type_helper() \
    { \
        return ::impl::adl_reader<__LINE__>{}; \
    }

#define SELF_TYPE decltype(self_type_helper())::type
```

And then...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A
{
    KNOWS_SELF_TYPE

    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(SELF_TYPE).name() << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    A::foo(); // Prints `1A` (mangled `A`).
}
```

Unfortunately this solution only works inside of static (and non-static) member functions. For example, it doesn't let you create a `typedef` to the self type at the class scope. But I assume it might be good enough.

Also it doesn't work in template classes, because `self_type_helper_dummy` is not being instantiated due to being unused. This could be solved by making it virtual, at the expense of making the class polymorphic.

Comment: and it wouldn't work inside a local class